# The sound is periodically "dying" when capturing with ffmpeg + directshow

Tags: ffmpeg, microphone, screen-capture, directshow, ffdshow

I am trying to capture video and sound with the following command

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -r 15 -i video=screen-capture-recorder:audio="Desktop Microphone (2- HD-5000 - Microsoft LifeCam.)" -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264 -y show.mp4
```

`screen-capture-recorder` is third-party dshow driver to capture screen and works ok.

`"Desktop Microphone (2- HD-5000 - Microsoft LifeCam.)"` is the name of my microphone, it is inside web camera of that name.

I found that recorder audio is periodically dying, i.e. becoming silent, fading out in vibrant noise.

The situation sounds like some level control works badly.

How to fix?

Comment: be careful, with newer ffmpeg’s you need to use “-framerate” instead of “-r” for the input framerate: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow#Specifyinginputframerate

Comment: can other apps record the mic ok for long periods of time? what about ffmpeg with only audio input?